# HTML/CSS Beginner - positioning of divs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my layout. I have a content div that I want to expand the more text there is in it. And at the bottom there's a div that should hold some contact info.

My problem: I can't figure out how to allow the content div to become larger without overlapping with my bottom div. I've tried margins and paddings but I can't seen get it to work.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

I pasted the code on Pastebin so this post wouldn't be so long. A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NpY66/

CSS: http://pastebin.com/7ztPs253
HTML: http://pastebin.com/YBqJJs3g

Comment: Make a fiddle instead, which provides a live preview: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Oh, cool! hers a fiddle!: http://jsfiddle.net/NpY66/

Comment: For starters, the values `float:top` and `float:bottom` don't exist. The only values you can use for `float` are left, right and none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, you need to use `clear: both;` on your footer style.

```
#bottom{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: 12px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
```

This will prevent floating `div` tags from overlapping.

[Updated version of your JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/MvMvL/)

Comment: Remove `float:bottom` there's no such value for the `float` property.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder - good point, I just added the `clear: both` rule, but I have now tidied up the whole CSS block to be safe!